# Android App is not showing for a tablet on Google play store

Tags: android, google-play, tablet, android-permissions

I am trying to search for [Device Locator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=osfg.com.devicelocator) on my Mi tablet but it is not visible. AFAIK it will not be visible for two things

1. OS version is less than minsdk version supported by app. - This is not the case. App supports Jellybean and Tablet is running kitkat.
2. Device needs some feature that tablet does not support. - I think this is the culprit but cannot think of one. I can see this issue on the browser which says incompatible with my tablet.

[image]

But I don't see any permissions related to carrier.

Permissions used are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.osfg.devicelocator.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Can someone please guide as to what needs to be changed here?

Comment: Does your tablet have a GPS chip on it?  Or does it rely on wifi?

Comment: @selbie I don't think it has a GPS chip. At least it's specs does not say so.

Comment: Have you added `<supports-screens />` in manifest?

Comment: @AnggrayudiH No I haven't. I don't think thats mandatory. I have release a couple of apps in past with no such tag and they seems to be working fine on all types of devices.

Comment: Try to add it, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was in permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

There require GPS hardware features and because of this app was not showing up on playstore for my tablet (it does not have GPS). However there dependency on GPS as location can be obtained from Wifi network as well. So adding following to manifest file resolved the issue

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

Updating the same apk on playstore showed following (GPS feature removed)

[image]